# Как задать ограничение (constraint) для столбца на количество вводимых значений?

Tags: postgresql

Нужно в PostgreSQL задать ограничение для столбца на количество допустимых значений?
Например, я хочу задать что бы уже существующий столбец мог принимать только максимум 10 значений

Comment: [Enumerated Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html)

Comment: А нам эти 10 значения известны во время (рано), когда задаем ограничение, а данные еще не пришли?  это меняет правила игры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

создайте констрейнт, которые будет выполнять проверку:

```
alter table myTable
add constraint checkConstraint
check (myColumn in ('value1', 'valiu2', 'value3'));
```

можно подсмотреть в [этот](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-check-constraint/) туториал

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать Enum столбец. По-мимо выполнения задачи, он позволяет прилично экономить память.
пример:

```
CREATE TYPE mood AS ENUM ('sad', 'ok', 'happy');
CREATE TABLE person (
    name text,
    current_mood mood
);
```

Отмечу, что такие типы регистрозависимы ('ok' != 'Ok') . В последствии тип можно добавить значениями через ALTER TYPE.

[Подробнее](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/datatype-enum).

Comment: вроде были какие-то проблемы с тем, чтобы добавить новый тип в енам. в новых ПГ пофиксили это?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov если честно не слышал о проблемах, на 12 точно все работает.